# Image not displaying reactjs laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, rest, axios

i want to get image from laravel storage and display it in react js

```
<img src={getImage(item.path)} />
```

getImage function

```
const getImage = (path) => {
    const di = axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/"+path)
        .then(res => {
          return res.data;
        });
    return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([di]));
}
```

my laravel controller function

```
public function download($image)
    {
        $path = "mail/{$image}";
        if(Storage::exists($path)){
            $file = Storage::download($path);
            return Response::make($file, 200);
        }
    }
```

that what i get

[image]

[image]

please help me to find solution i have this problem since week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return it like this

```
return response()->file($file, $headers);
```